# rtweet to scrape a whole thread of a twitter status？

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am trying to use R to scrape the whole conversation thread of a twitter status. I am exploring rtweet, which is the latest package for extracting twitter data in R. I could not not find any. I wonder if anybody could help
Thanks